# Bluetooth headset keeps disconnecting when idle on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth

I have Sony WH-1000XM3 bluetooth headset. It used to work normally on Ubuntu 18.04, before I upgraded to 20.04. Now the headset is routinely automatically disconnected when it's not used for some time (don't have exact measurement). The headset is still on (ie, pushing on a button I get the battery level annonucement), but the laptop has switched to its built-in speakers. And then the only way to get the connection back is to put the laptop to sleep and wake up again.

I have not experienced such disconnect when using the headset, ie in the middle of longer youtube video.

Perhaps it's not only audio bluetooth device issue, but something related to any bluetooth device that is considered to be unused by the OS.

Comment: Yeah I have this exact issue, too, though with a TOZO-T10-R bluetooth headset. I think it is also something related to any Bluetooth device that is considered to be unused by the OS, as I have the same issue when connecting a Bluetooth mouse directly using Bluetooth rather than the dongle it comes with.

Comment: My colleague also has the same issue with another Bluetooth mouse and headset.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this issue with one of my bluetooth speakers. You may try different things as suggested in similar posts on this forum, like connecting your bluetooth speaker using terminal instead, updating bluetooth/bluez, updating pulseaudio etc. (Information on these have been provided in the last part of my answer.) But none of them seemed to work for that particular speaker of mine. If you have already tried these things and still could not solve the issue, then read on! :)

Later I figured out that it was more of a speaker issue than that of Ubuntu because when I connect another bluetooth headset of mine, it does not disconnect after a while and also, the speaker which was getting disconnected showed the same behavior when I used it on Windows 10 and Android. Some bluetooth models disconnect after some minutes of inactivity so as to save the battery.

Therefore, there might be an option in your bluetooth headset to disable this battery saving feature. If there is no such option, then you may try this temporary solution but it works at least. Play any media on any media player on your PC, put it on repeat loop and then decrease the media player volume to 0%. This makes sure that your bluetooth headset is not sitting idle and therefore, prevents it from disconnecting.

I know this may not be a good solution for you but I thought to share it with you as it works at least. :)

(**Extra Information**) Other ways to solve the problem as has already been suggested in posts having similar problems:-

1. Connecting through terminal and putting it on trusted list:-
   Type these codes on the terminal

```
    bluetoothctl

    power on

    scan on

    connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

    trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

where, XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the bluetooth address of your headset.

2. Updating bluetooth/bolez

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
    
    sudo apt update
    
    sudo apt install bluez
```

3. Updating/installing pulseaudio

```
    sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth

    killall pulseaudio
```